# RSA256 for Google JWT

Tags: nodemcu

Looking at integrating with Google Cloud Framework IoT for a project. Running into an issue where GCF needs either RSA256 or ES256 for the signature of the JSON Web Token (signature appears to be the head and payload of the JWT encrypted and GCF will use the public key to verify). However, I don't see RSA256 supported in crypto.

I'm not well versed in crypto so can anyone help enlighten me here.

Am I just looking for the algo name in crypto or is this just plain not supported?

Is there a JWT module for nodemcu?

Comment: Don't know about MCU support for JWT (I don't think, as you've found, that it is properly supported). We've internally done a bunch with MongooseOS with success. It's still pretty fiddly, but it works.

Comment: Yeah seems like mongoose has the most support so far but it's a little un-nerving to have to adopt the whole framework.

Comment: Yup, I agree... There's a few more that seem to be trying to come online, but so far Mongoose is far and away the best I've worked with. It's basically just like working with Firmata on Arduino, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

May have found my own answer. From https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts

"Cloud IoT Core supports the following signing algorithms:

JWT RS256 (**RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256 RFC 7518 sec 3.3**). This is expressed as RS256 in the alg field in the JWT header."

Comment: Looks like none of this is supported :/